# Import ttf font in .ejs files

Tags: css, fonts, nestjs, truetype

I'm having a nestjs project and want to generate server side pdf using `notice.ejs` template. And I have a ttf font `Debrosee-ALPnL` and want to apply this font to all the `<h2>` element inside the html template.
I'm importing the ttf font in `notice.ejs` file as follows:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        @font-face {
            font-family: "newfont";
            src: url("../files_ttf/Debrosee-ALPnL.ttf");
        }
        h2 {
            font-family: "newfont";
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
   <h2>Some text</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

But here the problem is I'm able to generate the pdf out of this template, but the font is not applied to the pdf.
The folder/file structure is as follows:-

```
-- assets
    |-- files_ttf
          |-- Debrosee-ALPnL.ttf
    |-- templates
          |-- notice.ejs
```

I tried solutions from multiple post on how to import .ttf file, but none of them seems to work for me. What could be the issue for the font not applying?

Answer (score 0):

When making use of node.js and ejs to render static files like
style.css,app.js,font.ttf etc
you have make use of a built in middleware in express

Simply create a folder with name 'public' put in all your static files
and add the below line of code to your app.js or javascript file and it should work

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

for more information on serving static files with express refer to https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html